# Take the last n items in a splitted column Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

A simple question but couldn't come up with any valid solution. I want to split `foo+fee+fii+faa` by the `+` char and taking into `newCol` the last two occurrences, so:

```py
    df.withColumn("newCol", split(col("colA"), '+')) #.SOMEFUNCTION(-2:)
```

would need to give `fii+faa` as output. I tried with `[-2:]` indexes but it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: startPos and length must be the same type. Got <class 'NoneType'> and <class 'int'>, respectively.
```

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.slice.html  Array slice function. To get the length of the array.  you can use F.size function https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.size.html